# how to work more efficient with UI elements

Tags: unity

im working on a mobile android game that has many levels and same UI. for every level i have to assign the object and function of every button in every scene level.

is there more effiecient way that there will be no need to assign all functions in every scene?

thank you for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tag for the common UI objects. Get them in the Start() or Awake() with GameObject.FindWithTag("tag").

When you get the object you can access all the components in them in runtime as you assign at editor inspector.

After getting the object, for event triggers you will have to work with their delegates. [Handling event trigger delegates in runtime](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/854251/how-do-you-add-an-ui-eventtrigger-by-script.html)

Keep the tags meaningful. Will be a great help.

Edit: more useful link.

Answer (score -1):

if they have the same UI and the same behaviour you could transform all UI such like HUDs, In-Game Menus into a prefab intantiate or drag to your hierarchy. I did it for exemple in virtual D-Pad made of Button class and Game Over and Level Cleared Screens

Comment: yes i did the same but in very level you have to assign their event functions